# An AJAX HTTP error occurred using commerce coupon percentage

Tags: ajax, commerce

I'm able to create coupons with no errors. When I enter coupon code into the field and click on the submit button I get the following error.

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 500
Debugging information follows.
Path: /system/ajax
StatusText: Service unavailable (with message)
ResponseText:
```

Drupal version 7.28

Commerce Coupon Percentage 7.x-1.0-beta7

dblog messages

```
// first error
Rules Warning:
  Unable to get a data value.
Error: 
  Unable to get the data property code as the parent data structure is not set.
// second error
Rules Warning:
  Unable to evaluate condition commerce_coupon_discount_coupon_codes_exist_on_order.
// second error
PHP Error:
  EntityMetadataWrapperException:
  Unable to get the data property coupon_id as the parent data structure is not set.
  in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyValue()(line 438 of /homepages/
  36/d385915579/htdocs/bbp/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).
```

Comment: That means a fatal error happen when processing the AJAX petition. Check the dblog entries (/admin/reports/dblog, make sure db log core module is enabled). Also check your PHP log errors (log path depends on your system setup)

Comment: I edited the post to include dblog messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems an error in Commerce Coupon Percentage module. Your problem comes from the EntityMetadataWrapperException: when processing the AJAx petition something goes wrong and an Exception is throw. This is fatal, so Apache ends the petition with the status 500.

I think this a bug in the module code, so you may go the [issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/commerce_coupon_pct?categories=1) for this module and create a new bug report with your problem.

By the way, the Commerce Coupon Percentage is only comptabible with Commerce Coupon 1.x, check your are using a 1.x release.

Comment: You were right to suggest I look at the version of Commerce Coupon. After some considerable [effort](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/119015/what-is-the-proper-way-to-drop-database-references-for-an-uninstalled-drupal-mod/120766#120766) I was able to reinstall everything which cleared up the EntityMetadataWrapperException: Error for coupon_id however I now get one for currency_code and I still have the ajax error which may or may not be related. I'm going to ask a separate question to deal with the remaining errors and how to find out their causes. Thank you @tunic!